# Debian Jessie 8.9 Compiling Error for Cryptocoin Wallets "error: ‘::SSLv3_server_method’ has not been declared"

Tags: compile, make, gcc, debian-jessie

**OS**: Debian 8.9

**Wallet**: mooncoin-0.10.5-tokenblock

**All dependencies installed**: libssl, libdb4.8, libboost, miniupnpc, qt4, protobuf, libqrencode

**Installation instructions**: /mooncoin-0.10.5-tokenblock/doc/build-unix.md

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

./autogen.sh (last lines printed, not sure this is a problem)

```
Makefile.am:5: warning: user variable 'GZIP_ENV' defined here ...
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/distdir.am: ... overrides Automake variable 'GZIP_ENV' defined here
Makefile.am:48: warning: user target 'distcleancheck' defined here ...
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/distdir.am: ... overrides Automake target 'distcleancheck' defined here
src/Makefile.am:403: warning: user target '.mm.o' defined here 
.../usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am: ... overrides Automake target '.mm.o' defined here
```

./configure --enable-hardening (last line, may have an issue?)

```
Fixing libtool for -rpath problems.
```

make

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19,
             from rpcprotocol.h:16,
             from rpcserver.h:10,
             from bitcoind.cpp:7:
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp: In constructor ‘boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)’:
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:91:29: error: ‘::SSLv3_method’ has not been declared
 handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::SSLv3_method());
                         ^
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:94:29: error: ‘::SSLv3_client_method’ has not been declared
 handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::SSLv3_client_method());
                         ^
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:97:29: error: ‘::SSLv3_server_method’ has not been declared
 handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::SSLv3_server_method());
                         ^
At global scope:
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign"
Makefile:5503: recipe for target 'Mooncoind-bitcoind.o' failed
make[2]: *** [Mooncoind-bitcoind.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/darin/Downloads/mooncoin-0.10.5-tokenblock/src'
Makefile:6269: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/darin/Downloads/mooncoin-0.10.5-tokenblock/src'
Makefile:554: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I'm having the same issue with earthcoin and leafcoin wallets. After spending much time googling and trying to resolve this issue, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that SSLv3 support was removed in Debian 8, and the Boost library available in Debian 8, 1.55.0.2, requires SSLv3 where SSLv3 cannot be ignored.

I altered the file below by commenting those lines, so it no longer checks for SSLv3:

```
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp
```

Normally, I would not modify source libraries, but in this case, since SSLv3 does not exist in Jessie, this was the choice I made.

[image: Comment lines in libboost 1.55.0.2]